# How to create custom Exception and Error handler in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular

I develop a .NET Core 3 REST API using C#.

I read a lot about this topic, and I implemented a custom exception handler middleware, which is work well.

But I realized that the error messages are structured differently.

For example, I use .Net Core Identity and when I try to save a username which is already saved, then I get an HTTP 400 with the following error response: (Sorry about that, I can't post images.)

```
error Array(1){
  0: {
    code: "...",
    description: ".."
  }
}
```

And, I use too the Attribute validation, which gives this HTTPErrorResponse:

```
error: {
  .
  .
  .
  errors:{
    Password: Array(1) {
      0: "The field..."
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, my custom exception handler class gives an ErroDTO which contains a Code, and a description.

So the problem is there are 3 things, which give 3 different error responses, and I don't know how can I handle this, in Frontend which is an Angular project.

I would like to handle all errors and exceptions by my ErroDto class, but I don't know how to transform the Identity or Attribute errors.

I think that I could test the email and password validation directly in the endpoint instead of using Attribute, and I could test if the existing email, and the Identity won't be throw error. But I think it is not the best practice, and it will be a lot of boilerplate code.

This is my exception handling class:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;
        public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
        {
            try
            {
                await next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
            }
        }

        private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
        {
            var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // 500 if unexpected

            ErrorDto error = new ErrorDto();

            if (ex is WrongCredentialsException)
            {
                code = HttpStatusCode.OK;

                WrongCredentialsException wrongCredentialsException = (WrongCredentialsException) ex;

                error.Code = wrongCredentialsException.Code;
                error.Description = wrongCredentialsException.Message;
            }

            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { error });


            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make a custom `ErrorClass` of some sort. Then, make overloads or something that will be able to map any of the other Error Objects you work with to your custom class.

Comment: Yes I thought about it, but I don't know how to catch all the errors of Identity, and Attribute. Can you give me some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create custom Exception class

```cs
using System;
    [Serializable]
    public class EmployeeMgmtException : Exception
    {
    public EmployeeMgmtException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
    }
```

- Create an Exception Middleware class

```cs
     public class ExceptionMiddleware
      {    
           private readonly RequestDelegate next;
           private readonly ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> logger;
           private readonly ResourceManager resourceManager;
        
       }    
    
     public ExceptionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionMiddleware> 
             logger)
      {
                this.next = next;
                this.logger = logger;
                this.resourceManager  = new 
                ResourceManager("EmployeeException.API.Resources.Resource", 
                typeof(ExceptionMiddleware).Assembly);
      }   
       
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
      {
    
    try
     {
      await this.next.Invoke(httpContext);
     }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
     await this.HandleExceptionAsync(httpContext, ex);
    }
    }
                     
     private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
       {
         context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
         ErrorResponse response = new ErrorResponse();
        
         if (exception is EmployeeMgmtException)
          {
           context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            response.ErrorMessage = exception.Message;
          }
          else
            {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;             
        response.ErrorMessage = this.resourceManager.GetString("FailedToProcess", 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
          }
        
          this.logger.LogCritical(exception, exception.Message, GetProperties(context));
         return context.Response.WriteAsync(response.ToString());
         }
       }
```

- Register Exception Middleware filter in Startup.cs

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<ExceptionMiddleware>();
```